# implement simplification rule for special functions

Tags: sympy

I am defining two custom functions in Sympy, called `phi` and `Phi`. I know that `Phi(x)+Phi(-x) == 1`. How do I provide Sympy with this simplification rule? Can I specify this in my class definition?

Here is what I've done so far:

```
from sympy import Function


class phi(Function):

    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return -1*self.args[0]*phi(self.args[0])
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, arg):
        # The function is even, so try to pull out factors of -1
        if arg.could_extract_minus_sign():
            return cls(-arg)


class Phi(Function):

    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return phi(self.args[0])
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)
```

For the curious, `phi` and `Phi` represent the Gaussian PDF and CDF, respectively. These are implemented in `sympy.stats`. But, in my case, it's easier to interpret results in terms of `phi` and `Phi`.

Comment: How about defining `Phi` to return `1-Phi(abs(x))` when the input argument is negative?

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, @Stelios! Adding an 'eval' method to the `Phi` class, similar to the one in `phi` class, but having it return `1-cls(-arg)` works perfectly. Feel free to provide that as an answer so that I may mark the question as answered.

Comment: My comment was just a comment. I encourage you to write your own answer (nothing wrong with that) showing how you finally implemented the class.

Comment: There's no way to tell Add how to simplify things. There have been [some proposals](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/pull/12508), but nothing fully implemented yet.

Answer (score 3):

Based upon the comment by Stelios, `Phi(x)` should return `1-Phi(-x)` if `x` is negative. Therefore, I modified `Phi` as follows:

```
class Phi(Function):

    nargs = 1

    def fdiff(self, argindex=1):
        if argindex == 1:
            return phi(self.args[0])
        else:
            raise ArgumentIndexError(self, argindex)

    @classmethod
    def eval(cls, arg):
        # Phi(x) + Phi(-x) == 1
        if arg.could_extract_minus_sign():
            return 1-cls(-arg)
```